# Moving MS SQL Server installation files

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need to move the installation files for SQL Server 2008 R2 from where they currently reside (S:\Program Files...) to a new drive (yet to be created). My S: holds my SQL backups, active data files, and SQL Server program files.

I have only one idea on how to accomplish this:

1. Stop all SQL services.
2. Create the new drive for the program files with the letter J. (Drive letter doesn't matter.)
3. Rename S: to T:.
4. Rename J: to S:.
5. Move all the program files on T: to S:.
6. Start all SQL services.

Unless I am not considering something in this process the SQL Server will not know anything has changed.

If that is a horrible idea about the only other thing I can think of is to create a new server and migrate the databases there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fine, with a couple of caveats. Firstly, be sure that whatever tool you use to copy the files will preserver the permissions of the files and folders or you may not be able to start your server. Secondly, "sometimes" windows won't want to let your change drive letters around. If you are stuck rebooting, disable the SQL Services first or they will restart after the reboot.